# Computing multiple numbers with multiple operations

Tags: arduino, calculator, microcontroller

So I am creating a calculator that will compute numbers.I have this code(I will not include very basic codes)

```
long num1, num2, answer;
boolean mySwitch = false;
boolean do_subtraction_flag = false;  // when true we will apply subtraction
boolean multiply = false;
boolean divide = false;

void loop()
{
char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();

if(keypressed != NO_KEY)
{
    Serial.print(keypressed);



    if(keypressed > 47 && keypressed < 58)  // is between '0' and '9'
    {
        if(!mySwitch)
        {
            num1 = (num1 * 10) + (keypressed - 48);
        }
        else
        {
            num2 = (num2 * 10) + (keypressed - 48);
        }



    }

    if(keypressed == '=')
    {
        if(do_subtraction_flag)  // we want to subtract the numbers
        {
            answer = num1 - num2;
        }else if(multiply){

    answer = num1 * num2;
    }else if(divide){
    answer = num1 / num2;
    }
        else  // we want to add the numbers
        {
            answer = num1 + num2;
        }

        Serial.println(answer);
        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 0;
        mySwitch = false;
        do_subtraction_flag = false;
    multiply = false;
    divide = false;
    }
    else if(keypressed == '+')
    {
        mySwitch = true;
    }
else if(keypressed == '*'){
    mySwitch = true;
    multiply = true;
}else if(keypressed == '/'){
    mySwitch = true;
    divide = true;
}
    else if(keypressed == '-')
    {
        mySwitch = true;
        do_subtraction_flag = true;
    }else if (keypressed == 'C'){
      for (int i=0; i < 80; i++) 
      {
        Serial.write(8);  // print 80 times backspace (BS)
    }        
    }
}
}
```

Im confused here because I want to compute multiple number with multiple operands (eg., 2+1+3 or 2+1-2), but when i add another variable 'num3' what should I suppose to do with it? if i put it into the do_subtraction flag what if the user inputs 2-1+3?Is it possible to compute 3 numbers with this code?I'm getting confused here but let me know if you are also confused what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

Make an array to hold the numbers and operators that you input, then loop through them when the input == '='. Have your num1 always hold the result and num2 hold the next array value.